# Scala murmur hash vs Java native hash

Tags: java, scala, hash

I am learning scala and kind of confused on the hash code part of case classes.

As far as I have seen case classes provide an automatic generation of toString,equals and hashCode.

In java the traditional wisdom is that java hashcode uses a native implementation.

But in scala it uses [murmur hash](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala#L145)

My questions.

1) Java has native hashcode since the hashcode is machine dependant,but if scala uses murmur hash then how it is machine independent?

2) Scala has regular classes as well as case classes, do normal classes also use murmur hash?

3) If murmur hash is really the fastest implementation after point 1 then why does java still using a native implementation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MurmurHash is a fast high-quality hash.  Scala provides automatic hashCode for its collections, tuples, case classes, and most other library-provided objects (along with equals), and since many of these things get used in hash maps, it's important to have a decent default hash.  MurmurHash provides this.  As far as I know, Java hashes are also NOT machine-dependent, even if there are cases where they are implemented with native code.  What is important is that the algorithm is the same from machine to machine, which Scala's is because it's implemented entirely in bytecode, and Java's is because anything that is not in bytecode (I haven't checked everything!) was done carefully, presumably.

(At least for anything extending `java.util.AbstractList`, conventional wisdom is wrong.  It's not a native implementation at all, just a loop on an iterator that calls the `hashCode` method of each thing inside.  But the JVM is good at this kind of looping and math; why would you want it to be native?)

Normal classes in Scala do not override `hashCode` so they don't use MurmurHash.  However, most library classes that are not case classes *do* use MurmurHash--all the ordered collections do, for instance.  (It is not appropriate to use MurmurHash, which is order-dependent, on a set, where order does not matter.)

MurmurHash, despite being very fast, is not the fastest possible hash.  Java typically uses a `x(n)*31 + x(n+1)`-type algorithm for its hashing, which is even faster.  Unfortunately, it's also a pretty crummy hash.  It's very easy to have collisions.  Also, MurmurHash has a nice compromise between low overhead and fast speed overall, but other hashes (e.g. XxHash or CityHash) can be faster for large objects at the expense of a little more start-up overhead.  It is not a given, therefore, that everyone should use MurmurHash for everything.

Nonetheless, MurmurHash was chosen for Scala specifically because of measured defects in the simpler typical Java-style hash, and it has generally worked out well.  Why has Java not adopted it?  Possibly only because Java, as a more mature language, tends to change slower than Scala, and nobody has gotten around to it yet, and/or anyone who cares is already using their own custom hashing solution.

Comment: If I understand this correct scala choose murmur hash since it was the best available choice, but why normal scala classes choose default hashing? Maybe because of compatibility? Not able to draw the line on custom hashing vs default java hash

Comment: Default hashing is no hashing, just a memory address reinterpreted as a hash code (just like in Java).  That's as sensible as anything when you don't know what parts of a class matter.  Defining equals and hashCode in a sense express what it is that you think matters.

Comment: There are two kinds of "machine dependent": (1) Does the code execute on all machines? (2) Does the code have optimizations for specific CPUs. Murmur has different versions that optimize for 32 vs 64 bit and little vs big endian.

Comment: @ThomasFischer - The Scala code doesn't have optimizations for different CPUs.  We need a 32 bit hash anyway, and we can't in general grab big chunks of bytes, so all the big/little/64/32 bit stuff boils down to one default implementation.